# Can I use manage-bde as a different domain user?

Tags: active-directory, bitlocker

I use "manage-bde" in Powershell to remotely check the status of Bitlocker encryption on domain computers.

We have several connected domains, but for this lets say Domain1 and Domain2.
When I try to run manage-bde from my computer in Domain1 querying a remote computer in domain2 I get "Access Denied" due to it using my credentials from Domain1 that I am currently logged in to.

Is there a way to run manage-bde when logged in to Domain1 with credentials for Domain2?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a domain trust or a bunch of other horsing around, it is not easy across domains with *just* `manage-bde`. Combine it with `psexec` and move on.

Use SysInternals `psexec` (free) specifying remote computer, valid remote credentials, and the `manage-bde` command. Remote computer and valid remote credentials are part of `psexec` using this approach, not `manage-bde`. `manage-bde` would be executed locally on the remote endpoint.

For example from a domain1 workstation:

`psexec \\workstation.domain2.local -h -u domain2\bitlockeradmin manage-bde -status`